# Do women have greater reproductive success than men?

Tags: psychology, sexual-selection

What proportion of men who go through their whole lives and never find a mate at all, and what proportion of women do? And is the proportion of men greater than the proportion of women?

Comment: [Related](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/7051/which-sex-has-higher-variance-of-reproductive-rate-in-modern-societies-male-or/7059#7059)

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer runs along the same logic as this question: [Which sex has higher variance of reproductive rate in modern societies - male or females?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/7051/which-sex-has-higher-variance-of-reproductive-rate-in-modern-societies-male-or/7059#7059)

Because its easier for a male to have offspring with multiple partners, more women would typically produce offspring than men.  In polygamous cultures, [it can lead to significant differences of reproductive success between the genders.](http://www.academicroom.com/article/wealth-status-and-reproductive-success-among-mukogodo-kenya)